# Reading xlsx file using Java and sjxlsx api. Unable to get the original decimal data from xlxs

Tags: java, performance, iterator, xlsx, cell-array

I'm reading xlsx file using `SimpleXLSXWorkbook` class, below is the code.

```
public static void testLoadALL( ) {  
    SimpleXLSXWorkbook workbook =new SimpleXLSXWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/balamurugan.ar/Desktop/eclipse_wrkSce/Base Rates_12_05_2017.xlsx"));
    Sheet sheetToRead = workbook.getSheet(0);
    List<Cell[]> rows = sheetToRead.getRows();
    for (Cell[] row : rows) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            System.out.println(cell.getValue());    
        }
    }
}
```

In my `xlsx` file, having few decimal data in cell. While iterating the decimal cell, i'm getting extra numbers.
ie. Original Data in xlsx is `15.2315`,
In java while iterating cell, getting extra decimal numbers `15.23149999999999999`.
How to get the original decimal data?